# Django. Как привязать изображение к конкретной категории?

Tags: python, django

Допустим, имеется условная модель:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_lenth = 32)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/')
    ....
```

Создано несколько объектов с разными полями 'category' - category_1, category_2, category_3. В админке перечень этих категорий организован в виде выпадающего списка. В папке Media лежат 3 изображения - image_category_1.jpeg, image_category_2.jpeg, image_category_3.jpeg. Как сделать так, чтобы при создании нового объекта в админке, к нему автоматически, в зависимости от выбранного поля 'category', привязывалось соответствующее изображение из папки media?

Comment: Внутри класса def save (, и по схеме...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему у Вас категория это Chargiled  а не ForeignKey на другую модель.

Comment: А с какой целью мне добавлять ForeignKey на другую модель? Внутри класса 3 объекта-категории, у каждого должно быть своё конкретное изображение. По поводу перепопределения save - а если у меня 150 категорий будет, мне ветвить if-else для каждой категории? Не очень логично.

Comment: _при создании нового объекта в админке_ При создании нового объекта категории? Или у вас есть ещё другая модель связанная с категориями?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev при создании нового объекта именно категории

Comment: Хм. А если я создам новую категорию, но в поле `category` напишу матерное слово, а не "category_1", то что должно произойти?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev идея такая, что при создании новой категории, проверяется наличие медиа файла в media с именем этой категории + .jpeg. Если такого не находится, то в качестве дефолтного изображения указывается no_image.jpeg, который лежит в той же папке. Соответственно если создается категория с уже существющим именем (в модели unique=False), используется уже имеющееся изображение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import path
from django.conf import settings

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_lenth = 32)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file_name = self.category + '.jpeg'
        if path.exists(path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)):
            self.image.name = file_name
        else:
            self.image.name = 'no_image.jpeg'
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Оно! Благодарю.

Comment: Только работать это будет не только при создании, но и при изменении.

Comment: Если это проблема, то её легко исправить проверяя id.